# How to hide a div on line break

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a css way to hide an element **after** a line break caused by a window resize? I want a similar behavior of my nav bar like amazon. If you decrease the window size, the nav elements which have a lack of space collapse to a new line, but the elements are collapsing to a background layer so they dont have an impact on the layout anymore and become invisible.

The solution with `display:none` on specific screen sizes is not the way I want to handle the problem. `white-space:nowrap` and `overflow:hidden` also dont solve it correctly, because this method works only letter for letter on links, and not element by element (i.e. div).

As far as I read the amazon code correctly, they solved it with javascript. Im very interested in a "only css way". Has anyone a clue?

My css code is very simple for the nav + elements:

```
.site-nav {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;

  a {
    padding: 3px 10px;
  }

   a:hover {
   padding: 3px 10px;
   background-color: #e6f2ff;
   color: #000000;
  }
  
  li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

If I add `white-space:nowrap` and `overflow:hidden` to .site-nav I get a similar effect, but not the same. By decreasing the window size the letters of the link disappear one by one. But I want the whole `<li>` element to disappear at once.

BTW: The code is in a liquid file:

```
    <div class="grid grid--no-gutters grid--table">
               {% if section.settings.align_logo == 'left' %}
        <nav class="grid__item small--hide" id="AccessibleNav" role="navigation">
          {% include 'site-nav' %}
        </nav>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
```

#########

**Update 2:**
Using only `white-space:nowrap` without `overflow:hidden` in the parent div seems to be a good temporary solution since it switches directly to the next smaller media query appearance.

Comment: Provide code of so far you have tried and facing problem

Comment: I wrote it. I made an inline-block for the nav bar elements and added nowrap and overflow hidden to the parent div class. But this makes the link disappear letter for letter. I want the whole element to disappear if theres not enough space (--> same like div behavior)

Comment: Why you don't want to use media queries?

Comment: I use media queries for nav bar appearances, but this is not the best solution in this case, because the nav bar elements are created programmatically with liquid code in a for loop.    They shall disappear dynamically, when for example a pc user decreases the window size